# How to display standard input in WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, stdin, textblock

is there a way to display characters entered through standard input in a TextBlock in WPF?

I need to use a bar code scanner, which will input in some data. This data needs to be displayed line by line in the TextBlock. I'm sure there is a fairly simple way to do this, but I haven't been able to find the answer. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is that since `TextReader.Read()` is a blocking operation, you can't execute it on the UI thread without the UI locking up.

Where I'd start is building a class that a) implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and b) uses a `BackgroundWorker` that reads from `Console.In`.  If you need character-by-character input, the method would use `Read()`.  Every character it reads should be appended to a `string` property, and then the method should call `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`.

`ReportProgress` raises `ProgressChanged` on the thread the `BackgroundWorker` was created on (as opposed to the thread the `BackgroundWorker` is managing).  If this event handler raises `PropertyChanged` on the UI thread, then any bindings that are using this object will get refreshed.

The end result looks something like this:

```
public class Listener : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private BackgroundWorker _BW;

   public Listener()
   {
      _BW = new BackgroundWorker();
      _BW.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
      _BW.ProgressChanged += BW_ProgressChanged;
      _BW.DoWork += BW_DoWork;
      _BW.RunWorkerAsync();

      Input = string.Empty;
   }

   private void BW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
      while (true)
      {
          int ch = Console.In.Read();
          if (ch != -1)
          {
              Input += Convert.ToChar(ch);
              _BW.ReportProgress(0);
          }
      }
   }

   private void BW_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
      if (h != null)
      {
          h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Input"));
      }
   }

   public string Input { get; private set; }
}
```

...and in XAML, you use it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Input}">
   <TextBlock.DataContext>
      <local:Listener />
   </TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>
```

Disclaimer:  I wrote all of that off the top of my head, and it seems to work, but I'm sure there are bugs in it.  A real implementation of this would use a `StringBuilder`, not just concatenate characters onto the end of `Input`.  Also, there's no way to shut this down; the thread just dies when the program terminates.  That's probably undesirable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a dependency property wrapping the standard input, and databind it to the textblock?

Comment: You could do this if the getter did `ReadToEnd()` every time it was called, but then you have to have some way of knowing that there's new data in standard input and call the getter again whenever a new bar code gets scanned.